# SQL CLR calling Process.Start hangs or fails

Tags: c#, sql, clr, process.start

I have checked and there are many posts similar but I cannot solve this. This is a SQL CLR proc to run an exe that parses PDF files. I can run same code as myself in console app. Permissions are not an issue. I am dumping to event log and the ProcessStartInfo is full formed. UseShellExecute - I am not certain. I have also created a .bat file to execute the code - run it manually  - it runs fine. Via this CLR program ? Hangs or runs right away but does nothing. At wits end. My goal was to create the CLR using the Nuget from itext but I had a real hard time installing. SQL CLR doesnt support it but I tried anyway.

Thanks in advance.

```
[Microsoft.SqlServer.Server.SqlProcedure]
    public static void PDFToCSVViaExe_CLR()
    {

        ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
        string args = @"\\app\Systems\Universal";
        args = " \"" + args + "\"" + " \"" + "*" + "\"" + " \"" + "LVM" + "\"";
        startInfo.CreateNoWindow = false;
        startInfo.UseShellExecute = true;
        startInfo.FileName = "c:\\SqlCLR\\PDFRipper\\PDFToCSV.exe";
        startInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
        startInfo.Arguments = args;
        EventLog.WriteEntry(".NET Runtime", startInfo.FileName.ToString()+" " + args, EventLogEntryType.Warning, 1000);

        string folder = "C:\\SqlCLR\\PDFRipper\\LVM.bat";
        try
        {
            //using (new ImpersonationNamespace.Impersonation("domain", "user", "password"))
            {
                EventLog.WriteEntry(".NET Runtime", System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name + " OR " + Environment.UserName, EventLogEntryType.Warning, 1000);
                folder = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(folder);
                if (!Directory.Exists(folder))
                {
                    throw (new Exception("Directory does not exist for " + folder));
                }
                else
                { EventLog.WriteEntry(".NET Runtime", folder + " exists.", EventLogEntryType.Warning, 1000); }
                // Start the process with the info we specified.
                // Call WaitForExit and then the using statement will close.
                using (Process exeProcess = Process.Start(startInfo))
                {
                    exeProcess.WaitForExit();
                }

            }

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            using (EventLog EventLog = new EventLog("Application"))
            {
                EventLog.Source = "Application";
                //eventLog.WriteEntry(ex.Message);
                EventLog.WriteEntry(".NET Runtime", ex.Message + "Trace" + ex.StackTrace, EventLogEntryType.Warning, 1000);
                //eventLog.WriteEntry(".NET Runtime", ex.Message, EventLogEntryType.Warning, 1000);
            }

        }
```

Comment: try `startInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;` ... though I'd personally recommend you change to using externally activated SQL Service broker and move your PDF processing outside of SQL server.

Comment: I tried that, unsuccessfully. Yea, this is a hack for short term, whereby its a step in a Microsoft Flow. The exe runs in less than a second - once per day. Thanks for you input.